# What happens when an uninitialised pointer variable is deleted in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose if I execute an infinite loop(sentinel) in which there is an
uninitialised pointer which is being deleted after every single execution of loop,
So the question is , Is it possible for the pointer to access system variables which are being used to run the computer?
Well I searched for its answer and found a close one about dangling pointers but the answers did not specify whether it can have access or not to the system variables , and also even if it has can it be deleted to cause a problem to computer which is irrepairable? Edit:( I think I created a wrong impression about my doubt upon the readers , I never actually intend to do or have done it but in case such a condition arises what would happen? Is my question.)

Comment: you're deleting the same pointer over and over? or you malloc(), never intialize, and then free() it?

Comment: @MarcB has a good point: Could you be more specific what do you do with the pointer? Could you link the answer you are referring to?

Comment: No I would never do such a thing but in case if the program has some way of executing such behaviour then what would happen? This was my question. Sorry if I did not clarify my doubt.

Comment: @YugeshNaidu no that will not happen, probability is way too low. More likely your PC will die because a meteorite will precisely hit it's case.

Answer (score 4):

> What happens when an uninitialised pointer variable is deleted ...

Assuming that by "deleted" you mean something like `delete ptr;`, the behavior is undefined. If you're asking whether X *could* happen, the answer is yes, for any physically possible value of X. (Operating systems have safeguards against rogue behavior by individual programs. Those safeguards are not 100% reliable.)

> ... in an infinite loop?

That makes no difference.

Comment: "the answer is yes, for any physically possible value of X" this is pure theoretical, in practice that would not happen. Same as would infinite monkeys generate complete works of William Shakespeare.

Comment: @Slava: In practice *what* would not happen? If X is, as the OP asks, accessing system variables, then yes, it *could* happen if the OS safeguards happen to fail -- or if there is no OS, as on a small embedded system. An infinite number of monkeys *would* type the complete works of Shakespeare; find me an infinite number of monkeys (and typewriters) and I'll prove it.

Comment: Please don't, @Keith. It could just as well remotely kill my cat, of whom I am rather fond

Comment: @KeithThompson OP did not ask as if X is accessing system variables, but can a process with UB accidently acces system variables and ruin your PC. That is possible only in theory but would never happen in practice. The same as if you throw a random set of letters it is possible that they make Shakespeare's sonnet but you will not see it in your lifetime.

Comment: @Slava: How do you think malware works? (As for the infinite number of monkeys, you'd see the complete works of Shakespeare as soon as some infinite subset has had time to finish typing. The "infinite" part means it's not a possible real-world scenario.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I know how malware works, it is specially made to explain known vulnerability. But if you create a malware that will try to breach by changing random bytes that may succeed only once in couple million years.

Comment: @Slava: And the question was, and I quote, "Is it possible ...".

Comment: @KeithThompson and I agreed that in theory yes it is, but in practice it will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

n this case the program has undefined behavior. If the pointer is initialized by 0 then all is O'k.

Comment: initialized by null

Comment: [`nullptr`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#null-or-zero) is safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS. For good old DOS this is possible though very unlikely (most probably your PC would simply crash so you just need to reboot), for modern OS this is next to impossible to happen as normal process memory is isolated from system and you cannot access it. Though some programs can exploit security breaches to modify system data it is very unlikely this will happen by random badly behaving process.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the word `delete`, you `delete` what you have allocated using `new`, so in your case, as you are deleting an uninitialized pointer the result will be ***undefined behaviour (UB)***.

You are doing it in an infinite loop: ***You are just increasing the chances of UB!***

You can read more about [memory management](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt) on [https://isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/)
[double-delete-disaster](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#double-delete-disaster)

Comment: The chance is 100% fom the outset and cannot be increased.